# Libphonenumbers in Oracle Aplication, missing metadata: /com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/data/

Tags: java, oracle, metadata

I loaded all the classes and data files of Libphonenumbers into Our Oracle database with "loadjava". In the application calling the methods in PhonenumberUtil, I am getting the error as:

ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing metadata: /com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/data/PhoneNumberMetadataProto_US

I wonder if Oracle actually store the metadata in the the database as Java resource. Does anyone know how to reference to the metadata in an Oracle application?

Thanks.